# select distinct and partition by in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions

myTable looks like this:

```
id    rDate   r     rName
1     41086   0.2   ax_ax03_a 
1     41086   0.2   ax_ax03_a 
1     41086   0.2   ax_ax03_a
1     41087   0.4   ax_ax03_a
1     41087   0.4   ax_ax03_a
2     41086   0.12  ax_ax06_a
2     41086   0.12  ax_ax06_a
2     41086   0.12  ax_ax06_a
2     41087   0.5   ax_ax06_a
2     41087   0.34  ax_ax06_a
```

and so on

for every id i have a set of dates (needs to be converted using cast(rDate as DATETIME), a value (r) and a name. 
 I need to eliminate all the enteries (duplicates) which have at the same time the same id, rDate, r, rName .
 I was thinking at something in the lines of:

```
select  id,CAST(rDate AS DATETIME) over (partition by rName, id) as rDateNew, rName  from myTable
```

using sql server 2012

Comment: `select distinct * from mytable` would select distinct values. Are you trying to select distinct rows or delete the duplicates?

Comment: `select  distinct  id,CAST(rDate AS DATETIME) over (partition by rName, id) as rDateNew, rName  from myTable`

Comment: I think you can eliminate duplicates using `GROUP BY`

Comment: is there anything unique in a row?  (e.g. an auto-numbered id)

Comment: Nothing unique in the row. For the same id there are multiple dates and vlues. However one id corresponds to the name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use the `over` clause in your case, `DISTINCT` will eliminate all the duplicates in your table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, rDate, r, rName 
FROM Tablename
```

However, if you need to filter these duplicates based on a specific column from each duplication group, for example if you need to select the row with recent date, in this case you should use `OVER` clause:

```
WITH Ranked
AS
(
   SELECT CAST(rDate AS DATETIME) AS Date,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rName, id 
                       ORDER BY CAST(rDate AS DATETIME) DESC) AS RN,
     r, rName
   FROM Tablename
)
SELECT * 
FROM Ranked 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This will eliminate the duplicates and give you the row with the latest date.

Note that you can't use `CAST(rDate AS DATETIME)` with `over (partition by rName, id)` this is invalid, you have to use a [ranking function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) with it instead of the `CAST`.

Comment: I need to eliminate values from `r` and the dates for every id (the for every id there is a corresponding code in rName, and this group combination of rName and id have values for a period of time, in my case approx. 5 years). Will `SELECT DISTINCT id, rDate, r, rName 
FROM Tablename` yield the rows which have the same id,rDate,r,rName distinct at the same time or just remove duplicates over each column? I need at the same time

Comment: @CM2K - It will give you distinct values at the same time **across all the four columns**.

Comment: this was very helpful and learned something today. thanks for the example, I will need it soon! have a great day and keep up the good work!

Comment: @CM2K - You're welcome any time. Glad it was very helpful for you, have a great day you too :)